# Check if a diretory exists before creating it

Tags: ruby, ftp

Is there a way to check if a directory exists in FTP before creating it? I want to avoid the folder-already-exists error.

Comment: I've not tried net/ftp yet, but I guess you get an exception, if the directory exists (probably Net::FTPError or Net::FTPPermError), so you just catch this exception and ignore it.

Comment: @user1934428 That's what I have in place now. Just wanted to know if there is a better solution

Comment: @user1934428 _"catch this exception and ignore it"_ – empty rescues are usually a bad idea.

Comment: @Stefan you would need to verify that the specific exception means the directory already exists, but other than that there's nothing to do in the rescue.

Comment: @Stefan : Of course one doesn't ignore **all** exceptions, but only the one relevant to this case. The problem with net/ftp - at least from what I have found - is, that the exceptions are not documented well in the Ruby docs, so one would have to try out first what exception raises (also check the message parameter) in order to find out what to ignore.

Comment: @Muthukumar : You could inspect the parent directory using `Net::Ftp#list` and see, whether your directory is present, but if the FTP account allows more than one user to be active at one time, this is a possible race condition.